# Zxing quits after reading barcode

Tags: android, zxing

I have included Zxing barcode reader from source in my application. Everything is working alright, Except the barcode reader quits after successfully reading the barcode. It does not throw any errors and my applications `onActivityResult` is not even called.

How I'm calling Zxing:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.aeon.android2chrome.android.SCAN");
Intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Note : I'm using `com.aeon.android2chrome` (my package) so that the phone does not ask which barcode reader to open with if zxing is already installed. I have appropriately changed that in the Zxing manifest.

I also get a weird error in the log

> 02-04 20:29:46.710: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29716): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

No other errors. Could someone please give me a few points on what is wrong or what could be wrong?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After alot of scratching my head, I have found the problem. The problem was I had the tag `android:noHistory="true"` in my activity's manifest. removing it fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

I think I had a similar problem when trying to include the Zxing source code.
I solved it by using the zxing.integration.android package which opens the BarCode scanner application (or shows the user a link to install it). It's a better and cleaner practice to open the installed BarCode scanner application and not use some not-up-to-date source version you happened to download.

Comment: I have changed my code to use the intent with `IntentIntegrator` and removed all the code I added myself. I still get the same error and same behaviour.